# Several sites are not accessible to anyone on our network, but they work fine outside of our network

Tags: connection

Several websites are completely inaccessible from our network. Specifically, hunter.io, polymail.io, and 1password.com. I checked all of these sites from multiple devices and browsers and the all return an error. In Safari, the error is [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu7MO.png). When I try from my phone and turn off wifi, I'm able to access the sites using data. I have looked through our Cisco WLC dashboard and can't find anything that has changed from last week when the issue began. Can anyone help to point me in the right direction? I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Do some testing lower then the browser.  Can you resolve those sites names with a DNS client inside your network?  What happens if you attempt to do a traceroute to the resolved IP?

Comment: 1password (cloudfront) is using SNI.  Do your corp proxies support SNI?  hunter.io (cloudflare) has some extra unrelated certs, but that should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with basic stuff internally like do the addresses resolve to an IP address inside your network?

There are very few reasons that would cause the behaviour inside your network:

- Does the address resolve to an IP? Internal network DNS could be failing or not finding a result for those DNS names.
- Has content filtering or something other program blocked them by accident?

Comment: I would agree - the error message itself says DNS is probably the issue, and 2 of the 3 sites are `.io`, so I would definitely start with seeing why DNS might be behaving this way